# Limiting Update Frequency / Purging Update Cache

Tags: python, caching, asynchronous, refresh, frequency

I have a User Interface that receives asynchronous notifications from a Service that prompts it to re-read information from a Database.  The async notifications contain a primary key that can be used to retrieve the modified record.  Under load, I might get 10 or 15 notifications a second, but frequently with duplicated IDs.  Something like this:

```
{u'callback': u'job.modify', u'job-id': 1090, u'timestamp': u'2012-01-26 09:50:04.766'}
{u'callback': u'job.modify', u'job-id': 1091, u'timestamp': u'2012-01-26 09:50:04.767'}
{u'callback': u'job.modify', u'job-id': 1090, u'timestamp': u'2012-01-26 09:50:04.780'}
{u'callback': u'job.modify', u'job-id': 1091, u'timestamp': u'2012-01-26 09:50:04.808'}
{u'callback': u'job.modify', u'job-id': 1090, u'timestamp': u'2012-01-26 09:50:04.812'}
{u'callback': u'job.modify', u'job-id': 1090, u'timestamp': u'2012-01-26 09:50:04.829'}
{u'callback': u'job.modify', u'job-id': 1088, u'timestamp': u'2012-01-26 09:50:04.831'}
{u'callback': u'job.modify', u'job-id': 1088, u'timestamp': u'2012-01-26 09:50:04.836'}
{u'callback': u'job.modify', u'job-id': 1091, u'timestamp': u'2012-01-26 09:50:04.846'}
```

It would seem worthwhile to skip a few of the database reads in cases like this.  I'm working with a class, so my thought was to configure some sort of refresh interval.  This is what I have so far:

```
class myClass():
  def __init__(self):
    self.modified = set([])
    self.lastrefresh = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.refreshinterval = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds = 250)

  def onModify(self, data):
    self.modified.add(data['job-id'])
    if datetime.datetime.now() - self.lastrefresh < self.refreshinterval:
      return
    self.doModify()

  def doModify():
    ids = list(self.modified)
    self.lastrefresh = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.modified.clear()
```

Which works (mostly) but carries the potential to have a few updates left over.  Because these updates are received async I never know how many or how often they'll show up.  Any pending refreshes are handled on the next notification, but if the next notification doesn't come in a timely manner then ids sit in the modified set for much longer than the 250ms interval I want.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to make this work.  It requires the following modifications to the Class:

```
class myClass():
  def __init__(self):
    self.modified = set([])
    self.lastrefresh = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.refreshinterval = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds = 250)

  def onModify(self, data):
    self.modified.add(data['job-id'])
    if datetime.datetime.now() - self.lastrefresh < self.refreshinterval:
      return
    self.doModify()

  def doModify():
    if not self.modified:
      return
    ids = list(self.modified)
    self.lastrefresh = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.modified.clear()
    wx.CallAfter(self.purgeModifies)

  def purgeModifies(self):
    wx.CallLater(250, self.doModify)
```

It feels a little bit hokey to use `wx.CallAfter` and then immediately call `wx.CallLater`, but the onModify is happening in a background thread, which means that `wx.CallLater` throws a C++ Assertion Error.  `wx.CallAfter` returns control to the Main Thread, which allows `wx.CallLater` to work.  This gets me my "one more run" to handle any pending updates.